# How to store Singleton into user defaults?

Tags: swift

I have Firebase project with 3 viewcontrollers(main, feed, profile). I made 3 structures(Post, User and Product the latter of which does not matter). And I use Singleton to store the profile values. However the problem is when I am trying to set values into Firebase using the singleton values, it sets those values as empty strings **if I do not go to the profile view and let them load**.

So the question, how I can store those values into user defaults? So I shouldn't query all those values if I enter to the viewcontroller.

This is my `User` singleton mini version:

```
class CurrentUser: NSObject
{
    var generalDetails: User = User()

    static let sharedInstance = CurrentUser()


    fileprivate override init(){
        super.init()
    }

}

struct User {
    var userName: String,profileImageURL: String

    init()
    {
        userName = ""
        profileImageURL = ""

    }

    init(userName: String,profileImageURL: String){
        self.userName = userName
        self.profileImageURL = profileImageURL
    }  
}
```

And like this I use those values:

```
let currentUser: CurrentUser = CurrentUser.sharedInstance
currentUser.generalDetails. ...(e.g userName)
```

Comment: Where are you setting the `userName` and `profileImageURL`? There is no code here that is setting those values. Calling the `init()` function on `User` sets them to empty strings.

Comment: Sorry, I thought if I add it, it would go too big. Look edit.

Comment: That still isn't actually setting the `userName` or `profileImageURL`. Where do you have some code like... `userName = "Bob"`?